# Отсутствие запятой при сравнении

Tags: пунктуация

> Я знаю прекрасно этого человека: как он поступает, как действует. Он
>   как Рома.

Ставится ли запятая во 2-ой фразе, и если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

***Он как Рома.***

§ 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что **не выделяются запятыми** в следующих случаях:

в) если **оборот является сказуемым:** Жизнь как легенда.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125